# Hibernate many to many collection insertion optimization

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am new to working with databases and I have a Spring DATA JPA training project with HSQLDB that has 2 entities with child collections and many to many relationships.
One entity is called a Menu, and it contains a Dish list, and vice versa, a Dish contains a set of Menus to which it belongs.
When I try to insert a collection of dishes into a table, the Hibernate sends a separate call for each entity. Is there any way to optimize for Hibernate to send one complex query to save the entire child collection?
UPD.
Sorry for the mistake, actually I'm saving the Menu that contains the Dish collection, and not just saving the Dish collection.

```
Hibernate: 
    call next value for global_seq
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.atanava.restaurants.model.Menu
        */ insert 
        into
            menus
            (date, restaurant_id, id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert collection
        row com.atanava.restaurants.model.Menu.dishes */ insert 
        into
            dishes_menus
            (menu_id, dish_id) 
        values
            (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert collection
        row com.atanava.restaurants.model.Menu.dishes */ insert 
        into
            dishes_menus
            (menu_id, dish_id) 
        values
            (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert collection
        row com.atanava.restaurants.model.Menu.dishes */ insert 
        into
            dishes_menus
            (menu_id, dish_id) 
        values
            (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert collection
        row com.atanava.restaurants.model.Menu.dishes */ insert 
        into
            dishes_menus
            (menu_id, dish_id) 
        values
            (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert collection
        row com.atanava.restaurants.model.Menu.dishes */ insert 
        into
            dishes_menus
            (menu_id, dish_id) 
        values
            (?, ?)
```

Menu class:

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = Menu.GET, query = "SELECT m FROM Menu m WHERE m.id=:id AND m.restaurant.id=:restaurantId"),
        @NamedQuery(name = Menu.BY_RESTAURANT, query = "SELECT m FROM Menu m WHERE m.restaurant.id=:restaurantId ORDER BY m.date DESC"),
        @NamedQuery(name = Menu.BY_DATE, query = "SELECT m FROM Menu m WHERE m.date=:date"),
        @NamedQuery(name = Menu.BY_REST_AND_DATE, query = "SELECT m FROM Menu m WHERE m.restaurant.id=:restaurantId AND m.date=:date"),
        @NamedQuery(name = Menu.DELETE, query = "DELETE FROM Menu m WHERE m.id=:id AND m.restaurant.id=:restaurantId"),
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "menus", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"restaurant_id", "date"},
        name = "restaurant_id_date_idx")})
public class Menu extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    public static final String GET = "Menu.get";
    public static final String BY_RESTAURANT = "Menu.getAllByRestaurant";
    public static final String BY_DATE = "Menu.getAllByDate";
    public static final String BY_REST_AND_DATE = "Menu.getByRestAndDate";
    public static final String DELETE = "Menu.delete";

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @NotNull
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "dishes_menus",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dish_id"))
    private List<Dish> dishes;

    @Column(name = "date", columnDefinition = "date default current_date", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate date;

    //constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Dish class:

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = Dish.BY_RESTAURANT, query = "SELECT d FROM Dish d WHERE d.restaurant.id=:restaurantId ORDER BY d.name"),
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "dishes", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"restaurant_id", "name"},
        name = "unique_restaurant_id_dish_name_idx")})
public class  Dish extends AbstractNamedEntity {

    public static final String BY_RESTAURANT = "Dish.getAllByRestaurant";

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @NotNull
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Integer price;

    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bool default true")
    private boolean active = true;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "dishes")
    Set<Menu> menus;

//constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Menu repository where I haven't overridden save method yet:
I save menu with original method
**crudMenuRepository.save(menu)**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface CrudMenuRepository extends JpaRepository<Menu, Integer> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(name = Menu.DELETE)
    int delete(@Param("id") int id, @Param("restaurantId") int restaurantId);

    @Query(name = Menu.GET)
    Menu get(@Param("id") int id, @Param("restaurantId") int restaurantId);

    @Query(name = Menu.BY_REST_AND_DATE)
    Menu getByRestAndDate(@Param("restaurantId") int restaurantId, @Param("date") LocalDate date);

    @Query(name = Menu.BY_RESTAURANT)
    List<Menu> getAllByRestaurant(@Param("restaurantId") int restaurantId);

    @Query(name = Menu.BY_DATE)
    List<Menu> getAllByDate(@Param("date") LocalDate date);
}
```

Snippet of initDB.sql file:

```
CREATE TABLE dishes
(
    id            INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE GLOBAL_SEQ PRIMARY KEY,
    restaurant_id INTEGER              NOT NULL,
    name          VARCHAR(255)         NOT NULL,
    price         INTEGER              NOT NULL,
    active        BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurants (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_restaurant_id_dish_name_idx on dishes (restaurant_id, name);

CREATE TABLE menus
(
    id            INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE GLOBAL_SEQ PRIMARY KEY,
    restaurant_id INTEGER                   NOT NULL,
    date          DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT restaurant_id_date_idx UNIQUE (restaurant_id, date),
    FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurants (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE dishes_menus
(
    dish_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    menu_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT dish_id_menu_id_idx UNIQUE (dish_id, menu_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (dish_id) REFERENCES dishes (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (menu_id) REFERENCES menus (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

UPD2
Here is my spring-db.xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="${database.init}">
        <jdbc:script location="${jdbc.initLocation}"/>
        <jdbc:script encoding="utf-8" location="classpath:db/populateDB.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/hsqldb.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>

    <!--no pooling-->
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
          p:url="${database.url}"
          p:username="${database.username}"
          p:password="${database.password}"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
          p:packagesToScan="com.atanava.**.model">
        <!--p:persistenceUnitName="persistenceUnit">-->

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).FORMAT_SQL}" value="${hibernate.format_sql}"/>
                <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).USE_SQL_COMMENTS}" value="${hibernate.use_sql_comments}"/>
                <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).JPA_PROXY_COMPLIANCE}" value="false"/>
                <!--<entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).HBM2DDL_AUTO}" value="${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}"/>-->
            </map>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.atanava.**.repository**"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.atanava.**.repository**"/>

</beans>
```

And here is a persistence.xml file that I created:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="menu-persistence-unit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.atanava.restaurants.model.Menu</class>
        <class>com.atanava.restaurants.model.Dish</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: For using Hibernate efficiently, you should have a look at the pages of Vlad Mihalcea. He described the [ManyToMany relationship](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) with a `Set`. For optimising the insertion of many entities, you can have a look at the article about [batch processing](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Comment: Felix, thank you for your advice. I refactored it like this:

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = {
            CascadeType.REMOVE,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "dishes_menus",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dish_id"))
    private Set<Dish> dishes;

But Hibernate still sends a lot of requests for inserts.

Comment: Firstly, I am not sure about eager fetching. Just always use lazy loading and initialise the sets when needed. As I did not try your whole code base, I can just point out my observations. I realised that you use a `Set<Menu>` in the `Dish` class. However, in the class `Menu`, you use `List<Dish>`. 
My idea would be to first remove some things which Hibernate can create automatically, e.g. the manual database initialisation. Then, it might be easier to find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about batching in the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch

Essentially, you just have to set the `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` property in the persistence.xml to e.g. 20.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me.
Probably because I'm trying to save the whole menu at once, and not a batch of objects.
I save like this: `crudMenuRepository.save(menu)` where the menu contains a List or Set of dishes.

Comment: This should work. You can debug into `org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister#insertRows` to see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you Christian, I will try to debug in this way.

Comment: I tried to debug by this way, but for some reason this method was not called.
I updated my question and added my spring-db.xml config and persistence.xml file, which I created.

Comment: Maybe you should enable debug logging to see exactly what is going on. The query is logged out every time a statement is acquired for execution, but that doesn't mean it's recreated everytime. Most probably, it's reused for batching already.

Comment: Christian, thank you again. I'll try to do log in debug mode.
I also set a breakpoint on the constructor and I saw that the constructors of OneToManyPersister and of BasicCollectionPersister are being called. It seems that  BasicCollectionPersister does this work.